# How do i resolve this ildoonet / tf-pose-estimation installing issue for windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, computer-vision, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzz7y.png)I was installing the packages on my conda environment in order to run the pose estimation according to the tutorial from  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUjGLjOmF7o&list=PLX-LrBk6h3wQ17z1axCOAS1QVS1dvTEvR and the github page https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation where u have to run the requirement.txt file to install the 3rd party packages for it to run in the end `$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.

I had 3 errors. the first was missing Cython package that I already found and installed. The 2nd was an error: `Error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required` that i resolved going here https://medium.com/@jacky_ttt/day060-fix-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-629413e798cd and installing the necessary packages in the visual studio c++ build tools. But i came across a new error that even i can solve. I would appreciate any help. The error came on my anaconda prompt:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools, tensorpack
  Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\M S Tiwana\.conda\envs\tfposee\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MSTIWA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vjk9vvy3\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MSTIWA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vjk9vvy3\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MSTIWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-fdystmqn'
       cwd: C:\Users\MSTIWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vjk9vvy3\pycocotools\
  Complete output (19 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  running build_ext
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pycocotools
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\common
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\M S Tiwana\.conda\envs\tfposee\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -Icommon "-IC:\Users\M S Tiwana\.conda\envs\tfposee\include" "-IC:\Users\M S Tiwana\.conda\envs\tfposee\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpycocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pycocotools/_mask.obj -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
  cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
  Running setup.py clean for pycocotools
  Building wheel for tensorpack (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for tensorpack: filename=tensorpack-0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=291265 sha256=85cc191f624cecba1af9d7bfeff01bd6fd592c8763010a1468abc0c6ccedfeac
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\MSTIWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-cjd1_8p6\wheels\8f\c4\7d\b7ca213c76a0b78c772c6d3173364b8102d262acda1ec45207
Successfully built tensorpack
Failed to build pycocotools
Installing collected packages: pycocotools, slidingwindow, tabulate, msgpack, msgpack-numpy, tensorpack
    Running setup.py install for pycocotools ... error
```

Is there a visual studio c++ build tool install error ?

Answer (score 2):

pycocotools is for linux, since you're using windows 10

instead of using: `pip install pycocotools`

use this: `pip install pycocotools-windows`

https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools-windows/